# JavaFX media player in mobile

Tags: video-streaming, javafx

Does anyone have any tutorials in playing videos in javafx applications in mobile?

My codes strangely work only in desktop execution. But the official site of JavaFX says it plays in mobile phones. I used their sample code and guess what, it doesn't play on the mobile phone too.

Here is the sample code I used: http://javafx.com/docs/articles/media/EmbeddedPlayer.fx.jsp

Please help me guys. I'm on a dead-end here. =<

Comment: Does your phone support JavaFX? Not all phones do. And JavaME != JavaFX.

Comment: Yes it does. It's an HTC HD2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested running it in HTC HD2.

The video formats must be supported in the phone. (mp4, avi, etc... but no flv)